# Is there some good study book recommendation for ruby or ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am new to study `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails`, but there is short of study resources, and search google, that is of varying quality.

So, I don't know how to make choice, because choose a not that good book, I will waste the time to study it, result get little knowledge. I want to use limited time to get as much as the learning outcomes.

So, can you recommend some book for `ruby` and `ruby-on-rails` study resources?

Addition: If you commend the book, please state the reason, where is the good characteristic for study `ruby`.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc.

Comment: @lzzy I have question on ` meta.stackoverflow`, ask where to ask the recommend way to newer for study a new language, some one ask me to ask this kind question on `softwarerecs.stackexchange`, so I come.

Comment: Don't blindly trust people saying "ask there". Always make sure they are right. Each SE site has a `/help/on-topic` page you can check. And if you've caught one being wrong, tell him/her so – to prevent future cases of "misguidance". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl is a popular book that beginners should read. It teaches you how to build a blog in Rails and will provide a solid foundation.